# Tableau package for R

Tags: python, r, analytics, tableau-api

I have spent a lot of time searching for an answer to this, but have not found anything yet.

Are there any Tableau packages for R? I would like to be able to create Tableau charts (or a tde file) as an output from my R script. It seems like you can run some basic R scripts from within Tableau, but that will not work for my case.

This is one of the few links I have found relevant to what I am looking for:
[R-bloggers link](https://www.r-bloggers.com/basic-proof-of-concept-save-an-r-dataframe-as-a-tableau-data-extract/)

Would it matter if I were trying to go from Python -> Tableau?

Comment: People shouldn't use a common name ("tableau" means table or painting in French) for a new tool. This makes search by keyword less efficient.

Comment: You can now save a R data frame as an RData file, and the open it in Tableau directly -- very similar to what the article you cited  requested. Tableau added this a couple of years ago, since that article was written

Comment: I currently output to a csv file, so not sure if this will make any difference, but I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

While there are options for creating TDEs (as you've already found) and for working administration of Tableau Server, at the moment there are no open interfaces for creating Tableau workbooks from outside of Tableau proper. This is currently one of my biggest annoyances with the software.

The closest you're going to be able to get is to use the Python Tableau Document API (https://github.com/tableau/document-api-python). While that does not allow creating workbooks from scratch, it does have the most robust document editing capabilities of the various options (https://community.tableau.com/community/developers) available. The README on the Python doc API suggest that document creation may be coming. Sounds like something to watch.